# Why does C# allow creating an object with the same reference?

Tags: c#, object

Here is an example of my code:

```
Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox PB = new PictureBox;
    PB.Name = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

In this code when a user clicks the button, a new object of type `PictureBox` will be created. Then `Name` will be assigned the object. How's this possible?

I mean if user clicks again, another object with same reference will be created. How's this possible?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be?

Comment: you are literally saying that in your code. whenever button1 is clicked, make a new picturebox and assign a name value to it.

Comment: Your code is explicitly creating a new `PictureBox` object and setting the `Name` property. What are you expecting to happen here?

Comment: what do you mean by same reference?

Comment: Do you mean that on each click, a new PictureBox will be created with the same Name property? The PB variable only lives while inside that method, multiple controls can just have the same Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How's this possible?

The `Name` property on a `Control` is just a string property - you can assign it anything you want, so having multiple controls with the same name is just the same as having multiple text boxes displaying the same text, or any other class with a `string` property.

Note that, in your case, you're not actually *using* or storing the `PictureBox` you create in any way, so it's going to be eligible for GC as soon as your method ends.

Comment: The PB variable only lives while inside that method, multiple controls can just have the same Name. That's Correct,Thanks CodeBaster.

Comment: How can i set CodeBaster Comment as True and end this thread.